# C++ Trouble with overloading >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm working on a program and have debugged a lot of what I was doing wrong in it out. I have only one error and have read on stack and other forums about similar problems. But have tried to re-do it over and over with no positive results.

Error Shown in header code and it is:

**binary'>>' no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of the type'overloaded-function'(or there is no acceptable conversion)**

#### Month.h

```
#ifndef MONTH_H
#define MONTH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Month{
private:
        static string name;
        static int monthNumber;
public:
        //Default Constructor
        Month(){
        setName("January");
        setNumber(1);
        }
        //Input of month only constructor and assigning month number from input of name
        Month(string n){
                name = n;
                setName(n);
                if(name == "January" || name == "january"){
                        setNumber(1);
                }
                else if(name == "February" || name == "february"){
                        setNumber(2);
                }
                else if(name == "March" || name == "march"){
                        setNumber(3);
                }
                else if(name == "April" || name == "april"){
                        setNumber(4);
                }
                else if(name == "May" || name == "may"){
                        setNumber(5);
                }
                else if(name == "June" || name == "june"){
                        setNumber(6);
                }
                else if(name == "July" || name == "july"){
                        setNumber(7);
                }
                else if(name == "August" || name == "august"){
                        setNumber(8);
                }
                else if(name == "September" || name == "september"){
                        setNumber(9);
                }
                else if(name == "October" || name == "october"){
                        setNumber(10);
                }
                else if(name == "November" || name == "november"){
                        setNumber(11);
                }
                else if(name == "December" || name == "december"){
                        setNumber(12);
                }
        }
        //Input of month number only and assigning month name to that number
        Month(int n){  
                setNumber(n);
        }
        Month(int n, string m){
            monthNumber = n;
            name = m;
        }
        //Set the name of the month
        void setName(string n){
                name = n;
        }
        //Set the monthes number (and name for increment and decrement)
        void setNumber(int n){
                monthNumber = n;
                switch(monthNumber){
                case 1:
                        setName("January");
                        break;
                case 2:
                        setName("February");
                        break;
                case 3:
                        setName("March");
                        break;
                case 4:
                        setName("April");
                        break;
                case 5:
                        setName("May");
                        break;
                case 6:
                        setName("June");
                        break;
                case 7:
                        setName("July");
                        break;
                case 8:
                        setName("August");
                        break;
                case 9:
                        setName("September");
                        break;
                case 10:
                        setName("October");
                        break;
                case 11:
                        setName("November");
                        break;
                case 12:
                        setName("December");
                        break;
        }
    }
        //Return the name of the month
        string getName(){
                return name;
        }
        //Return the month number
        int getNumber(){
                return monthNumber;
        }


       //Overload the -- Operator
        Month Month::operator--(int){
        if(monthNumber == 1)
        {
        setNumber(12);
        setName("December");
        }
        else {
        monthNumber++;
        setNumber(monthNumber);
        }
    }
        Month Month::operator--(){
        if(monthNumber == 1)
        {
        setNumber(12);
        setName("December");
        }
        else {
        monthNumber++;
        setNumber(monthNumber);
        }
    }
        //Overload the ++ operator
        Month Month::operator++(int){
        if(monthNumber == 12)
        {
        setNumber(1);
        setName("January");
        }
        else {
        monthNumber++;
        setNumber(monthNumber);
        }
    }
        Month Month::operator++(){
        if(monthNumber == 12)
        {
        setNumber(1);
        setName("January");
        }
        else {
        monthNumber++;
        setNumber(monthNumber);
        }
    }

        //Overloading << and >>
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &strm, const Month &obj){
            strm << "# of Month : " << obj.name << " This Corresponds to the month : " << obj.monthNumber << endl;
            return strm;

        }
        //Error here
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //binary'>>' no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of 
        //the type'overloaded-function'(or there is no acceptable conversion)
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &strm, Month &obj) {
            strm >> obj.setNumber >> obj.setName;
            return strm;
        }

};
#endif
```

#### source.cpp

```
#include "Month.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Month coolio, first(1), second("June");
    coolio++;
    second--;
    ++first;

    cout << "Enter the month number: " << endl;
    cin >> coolio;

    cout << coolio;
    cout << second;
    cout << first;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a reason for your members being `static`. I just can't think of what it could possibly be.

Comment: You are trying to read into member functions. Read into the data members.

Comment: Get rid of the `using namespace std;` in the header file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I think that you confused Stack Overflow with CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you know where the error might be why not post a stripped down version of the class to save everyone's time? See [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about that, thought I would throw it all in there. Wont happen again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot read data from an input stream, and combine that with a method call. You need to read the data into a temporary `int` and a temporary `string`, and then use these `int` and `string` to call the setters, like this:

```
friend istream &operator>>(istream &strm, Month &obj) {
    int number;
    string name;
    strm >> number >> name;
    obj.setNumber(number);
    obj.setName(name);
    return strm;
}
```

Moreover, since `>>` is declared a `friend`, you can read directly into `obj`'s member variables.

Comment: +1, Even more direct. its a *friend* ed operator. Unless someone someday expects some stealthy reason to inject nefarious activity in a setter, you could simply read directly into `obj.name` and `monthNumber`, since there is no check on `strm` before invoking the setters.

Comment: Yeah, what you have is totally the right way to do it to preserve the pristine state of `obj` if a stream read *failed*. I.e. `if (strm >> number >> name)` *then* fire the setters (or direct assignment to members; either way). Just food for the OP to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions on how to simplify your program (so the rest of us don't have to wade through hundreds of lines of code):

### Assign To Members directly

You don't need to call `setName` within the `setNumber` method.
Access the `name` variable directly.

### One Text Case, One compare

Your code will fail for the case jUNe.
You could convert your month name to all lower case or all upper case before you compare.  This reduces your `if-else` ladder by half.
Search the web for "c++ transform toupper".

### Remove Month Compares

There's a fancy technique for *mapping* month names to numbers, but we'll not use that.  You can use an array instead.  Let the array index represent the month number:

```
static const char month_number_to_name[13] =
{
  "Nothing",
  "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june",
  "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december",
};

// ...
std::cout << "The name of month 10 is: "
          << month_number_to_name[10]
          << "\n";
```

### Save Month Name or Number

There is no need to save both the month name and number.  With the translation array above you can convert between name and number.
I recommend keeping the month number variable.  If you need the name, using the month number to get the name, the process the name.

### Small size, small quantity of defects

There is much research in the programming industry that states the longer a program is, the high probability it will have more defects than a shorter one.  Just consider the typing alone.  More letters typed increases the chance for a typo.

Use data structures to your advantage to reduce your program size.